# How to make a weighted mean inside a summarise_if

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing a line per company, with different variables (some numeric, others not):

```
    data <- data.frame(id=1:5,
                 CA = c(1200,1500,1550,200,0),
                 EBE = c(800,50,654,8555,0),
                 VA = c(6984,6588,633,355,84),
                 FBCF = c(35,358,358,1331,86),
                 name=c("qsdf","xdwfq","qsdf","sqdf","qsdfaz"),
                 weight = c(1, 5, 10,1 ,1))
```

I would like to summarise all numeric variables by a weighted sum. If I wanted a simple sum I would do:

```
data %>% summarise_if(is.numeric,sum)
```

but I don't see how to define a weighted sum.

I tried:

```
w.sum <- function(x) {sum(x*weight) %>% return()}
```

but without any success.

Comment: How about `data %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(sum(.*weight)))`  I think it is better to use `summarise_at` here ue `data %>% summarise_at(names(.)[2:5], funs(sum(.*weight)))`

Comment: It works perflectly thank you very much ! why do you prefer your second solution ?

Comment: Thanks, it is only because that id column is numeric and you may not need to do the `sum` of 'id's.  I would assume that in your original dataset, it may not be the case and have strong justification to use `summarise_if`

Comment: @Malta, Should your title display "weighted sum" instead of "weighted mean"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use it inside the `funs`

```
data %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(sum(.*weight)))
```

Note that the above is based on the condition that if the columns are `numeric` class.  Based on the example the 'id' column is `numeric`, which may not need the `summarise`ation.  A better option would be `summarise_at` to specify the columns of interest

```
data %>%
  summarise_at(names(.)[2:5], funs(sum(.*weight)))
```